# Conversion Single To Hex

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert the following VB6 code to VB.NET:

```
Public Function SingleToHex(ByVal Tmp As Single) As String
    Dim TmpBytes(0 To 3) As Byte
    Dim TmpSng As Single
    Dim tmpStr As String
    Dim x As Long
    TmpSng = Tmp
    Call CopyMemory(ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal VarPtr(TmpSng), 4)
    For x = 3 To 0 Step -1
        If Len(Hex(TmpBytes(x))) = 1 Then
            tmpStr = tmpStr & "0" & Hex(TmpBytes(x))
        Else
            tmpStr = tmpStr & Hex(TmpBytes(x))
        End If
    Next x
    SingleToHex = tmpStr
End Function
```

I tried to find a function in the "Conversions" namespace, but I did not find any.

Can anybody tell me how this can easily be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Function SingleToHex(ByVal Tmp As Single) As String
    Dim arr = BitConverter.GetBytes(Tmp)
    Array.Reverse(arr)
    Return BitConverter.ToString(arr).Replace("-", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you you so much! I have converted "Dim arr" to "Dim arr() As Byte". Do you perhaps also know how to convert a Hex to Single?